# Django_filters changing label, how to figure out default filter type

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using django_filter, displaying it in my own way in template. I want to edit label of one of the filters. To do that I need to provide filter type. It works great in default but I can't figure out which filter type is used. This field in my model looks like this:

```
class Zamowienie(models.Model):
    zam_kontrahent_fk = models.ForeignKey(Kontrahent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['knt_kod']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kontrahenci'

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.knt_nazwa)
```

On template it looks like typical select box. I figured out its not `django_filters.ChoiceFilter` but `django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter`. I tried using its `queryset` option but it only displays list of primary_keys (1 instead of 'name' field from the table foreign_key is)

```
class ZamowienieFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    zam_status = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(label='Status', queryset=Zamowienie.objects.order_by('zam_kontrahent_fk').values_list('zam_kontrahent_fk', flat=True).distinct())

    class Meta:
        model = Zamowienie
        fields = [
            'zam_kontrahent_fk',
        ]
```

Is it correct way to handle that? I didn't find a way to log default filter behaviour, it would help a lot, simply copying this fragment. Any idea how to display values, not list of primary_keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Zamowienie` doesn't have a `def __str__` defined.  `__str__` is used as the default representation for the ModelChoiceFilter options.

You're also using `.values_list('zam_kontrahent_fk', flat=True)`, which will probably eliminate django-filter's ability to call `__str__`.

Comment: I had `def __str__` defined, forgot to add it, I'll comment my question. When I remove `.values_list('zam_kontrahent_fk', flat=True)` it simply shows `__str__` of `Zamówienie` but I need only the value of `zam_kontrahent_fk`, not `__str__`

Comment: I don't know why didn't I just call `queryset=Kontrahent.objects.all()` and instead I tried to use foreign_key. Your response helped me figure it out, thanks.